# QRY returning error if value is blank?

Tags: ms-access

I am running the below expression to compare the diffence of 2 dates. If both dates are in the cell I would like it to return a 0 but if Date2 is blank I would like the difference to show. Right now I just get #ERROR if there is no date in date2. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
expr2: NetWorkDays([Date1],[Date2])

Option Compare Database 

Public Function NetWorkdays(dteStart As Date, dteEnd As Date) As Integer 

Dim intGrossDays As Integer 
Dim dteCurrDate As Date 
Dim i As Integer 

intGrossDays = DateDiff("d", dteStart, dteEnd) 
NetWorkdays = 0 

For i = 0 To intGrossDays 
dteCurrDate = dteStart + i 
If Weekday(dteCurrDate, vbMonday) < 6 Then 
End If 
Next i 

End Function
```

Comment: What are you intending to do with `NetWorkdays = 0`

Comment: Sometimes the field is blank and if so I need to know how long it has been blank since the first field date was entered

Comment: can you please post the code where you are calling the function?

Comment: I just use NetWorkDays([Date1],[Date2]) and Date2 is blank. I get invalid use of Null if i do NetWorkdays(#2012-1-1#,Null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function will always return 0 if you don't remove the `NetWorkdays = 0` from the function, and you will continue you to get an error if you don't wrap where you call the function in an if statement like this:

```
If Not IsNull(Date2) Then
txtResult = NetWorkdays(Date1, Date2)
Else
txtResult = 0
End If
```

txtResult being the textbox you want to display your results in.

You may want to look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258196(v=office.12).aspx.  It is a function designed for access to calculate the number of workdays between two dates.

Using this function you should get the results you want doing something like this:

```
If Not IsNull(Date2) Then
txtResult = 0
Else
txtResult = Work_Days(Date1, Now())
End If
```

Comment: Still getting #ERROR not sure

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to do the difference between date1 and Now()/todays date if the cell is empty. If date2 contains a date output a zero.

Comment: I'll adjust my answer to account for that, assuming your going to use the function in the link provided.

Comment: Sorry I keep editing my answer.  I was confused about date2.  You do want to say Not IsNull.  The function is also copy/paste.  You shouldn't have to edit it at all.

Comment: I receive a type mismatch error when I tried that link/code ? Work_Days(#2012-1-1#, "") thank you for helping  The code works if there is a date in date 2 but I need it to work when date2 is "" so it would be the difference between date1 and now

Comment: Ok, so if there is a value in date2 you want to calculate the date based off that value.  If there is no value in date2 you want to calculate based off of Now()?

Comment: If there is a date in Date2 I want it to output a 0. If there is no date in date2 I want it to take the difference between date1 and now()  Thank you

Comment: Ah, I just forgot to say `txtResult = Work_Days(Date1, Now())` in the code snippet.  Just to clarify you do want the difference between dates to ignore weekends, right?

Comment: Exactly, I need to just do working days and if date2 is empty ill need the difference

Comment: The code provided should work then. `If Not IsNull(Date2) Then
txtResult = 0
Else
txtResult = Work_Days(Date1, Now())
End If`

Comment: Problem is this i am not using a textbox this is just an access qry populating a column. I am using the code provided in the link and seems to work but it is doing the opposite of what I need. It calculates the difference if there is a date in date2 if there is no date in date2 it inserts a 0 when I need it the other way around. Thanks again for your assistance

Comment: Have you gotten the code snippet from my most recent answer?  That code should return 0 if there is a value in date2.  If there is no value then it should return the difference.  The txtResult can be anything.  I was just assuming you were using a textbox, but you can assign the results to anything.